# In next js 13.2, when open a page in new tab, the URL changes but the content that displays is of homepage

Tags: next.js

I used next js 13.2 for my project, every thing goes perfect but I faced a problem and that is when open a page in new tab, the URL changes in the address bar of the desired page but the content that displays is of homepage.
Here's my website link : https://logovinyl.com/

I tried updating my .htaccess file but the problem didn't solved.

Here's the code for .HTACCESS file :

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]